# core data dictionary with relationships superclass

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a class that inherits from NSManagedObject, say subClassA, and another class that inherits from subClassA, say subClassB. If I have an entity of class subClassB, say entityB and I set

```
NSDictionary* relationshipsDictionary = entityB.entity.relationshipsByName;
```

is there a way to distinguish between those relationships in relationshipsDictionary that are inherited from subClassB and those that are only part of subClassA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"subClassA" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
NSDictionary* relationshipsDictionary = [entityDescription relationshipsByName];
```

Mind that you need to give the name of the entity, not its class.

Source: `NSEntityDescription` Class Reference

Comment: Sweet, exactly what I was looking for. I did not dig deep enough into the entityDescription class.